# IIS / ASP.NET Ajax failed to load

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, web-config

I have one project made a few weeks ago that is running perfectly and when i tried to copy the website to the final place it started showing this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ScriptResource.axd:3
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ScriptResource.axd:3
Uncaught Error: The structure of ASP.NET Ajax client failed to load. VM5538 home:47
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ScriptResource.axd:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
```

The thing is, i only get this error on the website in the new folder, if i try to open it using the Visual Studio at old place i get no error.

I have already tried to create a new project in the final folder from scratch and put my files and i continue to get it.

I think it might be web.config/IIS related but i can't find what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `final place`? you mean the web server? What's the version of win server and IIS the website has been deployed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by rewriting my rules in a different order. It was because i have this different URL schema and my web.config was messing something on the verification.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and in my case it was caused by having a default Route defined. Fixed by adding an ignore rule before the default, like so:

```
   routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); // this is the fix!

   routes.MapPageRoute("StandardRoute", // default route
       "{*value}",
       "~/Default.aspx");
```

More here: http://blog-rat.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/url-routing-causing-to-load-loginaspx.html

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by rewriting my rules in a different order. It was because i have this different url schema and my web.config was messing something.

Thanks anyway for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try any of the below solutions and see if it fixes your issue.

**1.** You may need to add this under `<httpHandlers>` of `<system.webServer>` in `web.config` file

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpHandlers>
     ....
    <add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
   </httpHandlers>

</system.webServer>
```

**2.** It may likely that the `.axd` extension is not defined in the virtual directory mappings. Go to `IIS manager` to the properties of the virtual directory, click on the Configuration button, select the Mappings tab. You have to have the .`axd` extension defined to open with aspnet_isapi.dll. Uncheck `Check that file exists` checkbox as `WebResource.axd` and `ScriptResource.axd` are not actual files. The navigation options might defer depending on the version of IIS you're using.

**3.** Create an empty `.txt` in the application root and rename it to `ScriptResource.axd`

Comment: The second and third options didn't work and the first one gave me an error on web.config:

500.19 - Internal Server Error - The solicited page can not be accessed because the configuration data related to the page are invalid.

Comment: After using only the third option and removing some stuff from my web.config i got most of errors fixed but still have one:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < WebResource.axd:3